# No bundle URL present in custom React Native project

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to make an existing iOS app use React Native and therefore I wrote the code for bridging the two manually and not using the CLI tool provided. I want the `RCTBundleURLProvider` to detect the IP address of the bundle server automatically, like in the apps generated by the CLI tool.

Finally, when I run the app:

```
react-native run-ios
react-native start --> the bundle server doesn't start automatically, which is strange
```

When loading the React Native bundle in the simulator or device, the error **No bundle URL present** comes up.

Doing clean / npm install / running react-native run-ios doesn't help. Setting the URL directly in the code works, so this isn't a firewall/AppTransportSecurity issue.

What am I missing?

`AppDelegate.m` - `jsCodeLocation` returned by `RCTBundleURLProvider` is equal to `null`:

```
...
- (void) loadReact:(NSDictionary*) launchOptions {

    NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
    // this WORKS --> jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios"];

    NSLog(@"JSCodeLocation:%@",jsCodeLocation); // jsCodeLocation equals null 

    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                        moduleName:@"MyModule"
                                                 initialProperties:nil
                                                     launchOptions:launchOptions];
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc.view = rootView;

    rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
...
```

`RCTBundleURLProvider.m` looks for a file named `ip.txt`, which appears to be missing.

```
...
- (NSString *)guessPackagerHost
{
  static NSString *ipGuess;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSString *ipPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ip" ofType:@"txt"];
    ipGuess = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:ipPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
               stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
  });

  NSString *host = ipGuess ?: @"localhost";
  if ([self isPackagerRunning:host]) {
    return host;
  }
  return nil;
}
...
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "MyModule",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've opened [**an issue**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12754) on React Native about it some time ago.

Here are some solutions:

1. - Run `react-native run-ios`
   - When the error appears, run `npm install`
   - Then run `react-native run-ios` again
2. Add `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` to `info.plist`
3. Make sure you have `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your hosts
4. Kill any other proccess `sudo lsof -i :8081`, then `kill -9 <PID>`
5. Remove `YOUR_PROJECT/ios/build/` then `react-native run-ios` again

I hope one of these solutions will solve your issue. If not, you can find more options on [**the issue**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12754).

Comment: It appears to be a different problem, the URL is reachable and can be entered manually. What fails is the retrieval of the bundle URL.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this "no bundle url present" error today. This worked for me:

- Open a terminal window
- cd into YOUR_PROJECT/ios
- Remove the **build** folder with rm -r build
- Run react-native run-ios again

Answer (score 0):

run the following code:

```
killall -9 node
rm -rf ios/build
react-native run-ios
```

it will open launchpackager.command and the application will install on the ios simulator